# Framework 4.0 not registered on web server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, frameworks, .net-4.0

[image][image][image]When i tried create project on MVC3, it gives me an error that **framework 4.0 is not registered with Windows server..**

When i tried to install framework 4.0 it showed that i already have it..
When i search for solution on Microsoft website its says you don't need 4.0 as 4.5 will cover it..
-I check windows feature ON/OFF there it shows i have framework 4.6 which is active
- I check Program & feature there it shows .net framework 4.5 multi targeting pack installed..
- i registered all features of 4.5 using **dism** successfully..
- i tried command prompt method but its not supporting on Windows 10..

I still getting that error please guide me..!

Comment: installing the framework on the server is not the same as registering it with IIS, which is not the same as setting the application itself to use 4.x. You need all the steps. There should be a guide online somewhere if you search.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command from commend prompt C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -h to register framework 4.0 in IIS(websserver)